# Calling a component vue that exists on parent and child by ref

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a little problem and I didnt find any solution to it.

So I have a confirmation-dialog made by me that I call with href. I have something like this

Child:

```
<confirmation-dialog
  ref="confirmationDialog"
  confirmationBtn="Delete"
  :msg="'Do you really want to delete'"
  @confirmed="deleteConfirmed"  >
</confirmation-dialog>
```

Parent:

```
<confirmation-dialog
  ref="confirmationDialogChat"
  confirmationBtn="End chat"
  msg="Do you really want to leave the help chat?"
  @confirmed="closeChat"
></confirmation-dialog>
```

I call them with something like this:

Parent:

```
chatDialog() {
  let dlg = this.$refs.confirmationDialogChat;
  dlg.show();
},
```

Child:

```
delete() {
  let dlg = this.$refs.confirmationDialog;
  dlg.show();
},
```

The problem is that I need the component on Parent, and on child, so when I call the child component with a different ref, the component that appears is the Parent component, and not the child one! I dont understand why, because the ref its different, so how can I manage this?

Update [Confirmation Dialog]:

```
    <template>
  <!-- Button trigger to Show modal - HIDDEN -->
  <button
    ref="hiddenButtonToShowDialog"
    type="button"
    class="d-none"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    data-bs-target="#confirmationModalId"
  >
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="confirmationModalId"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="confirmationModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Button trigger to Hide modal - HIDDEN -->
      <button
        ref="hiddenButtonToHideDialog"
        type="button"
        class="d-none"
        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
      >
      </button>

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5
            class="modal-title"
            id="confirmationModalLabel"
          >{{ title }}</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{ msg }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          >{{ cancelBtn }}</button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="clickConfirm"
          >{{ confirmationBtn }}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ConfirmationDialog',
  props: {
    cancelBtn: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Cancel'
    },
    confirmationBtn: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Confirm'
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Confirmation'
    },
    msg: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
  },
  emits: [
    'show',
    'hide',
    'confirmed'
  ],
  methods: {
    show () {
      //Easy way to show the modal:
      let btnToShowModal = this.$refs.hiddenButtonToShowDialog
      btnToShowModal.click()
      this.$emit('show')
    },
    hide () {
      //Easy way to hide the modal:
      let btnToHideModal = this.$refs.hiddenButtonToHideDialog
      btnToHideModal.click()
      this.$emit('hide')
    },
    clickConfirm () {
      this.hide()
      this.$emit('confirmed')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It depends on what's confirmation-dialog and how it works.

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought that if the href would be different, the calls would work fine! I updated my response with confirmation dialog

Comment: I'm not sure how it's possible. They don't compete over the same component instance, so these refs really refer to different dialog instances that aren't related. It's possible that both parent and child show a dialog, and the one from a parent covers the one from a child. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem that can be debugged

Comment: @EstusFlask Thats my point! The refs refer to a different dialog and the function that calls it its different to! The component its not the same but when compiled they stay together! So I dont know why when I call one ref, the other One shows up, maybe this create an alias to the confirmation-dialog and opens it

Comment: It's not shown how exactly open/close is handled outside dialog component. It's possible that it's triggered in both components by mistake. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve